# Is there a way to prevent Nook from auto selling a spot?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

My SO has that problem, but I never encountered it myself.

It seems that Nook, when someone moves out, will auto fill the spot left with a random villager, and that in usually 2-3 days, sometimes even the day straight after the villager has left.

That makes her mad because she wants to find the perfect villager, but gets stuck with a random villager before she could do a good amount of mystery islands to find it.

So is there a way to tell Nook to not auto sell the spot? (Or is there something that she does that it 'auto sells' the spot or at least looks like that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer **no**. Nook will eventually fill empty plots.

One thing doable is to not build all the spots if it's not already done, recruit a wanted villager on an island and only then build the plot.

<sub>I couldn't find a source apart from my own experience, feel free to add one.</sub>

Comment: [Per Polygon](https://www.polygon.com/animal-crossing-new-horizons-switch-acnh-guide/2020/3/20/21166529/nook-miles-tickets-islands-mystery-island-tours): "If you have any open housing lots on your island, you can invite any of the villagers you find on Nook Miles island to come stay with you. Each island will have one villager, unless your town is full. **If you’re unable to host any new villagers, there won’t be an animal on the island.**"

Comment: So it sounds like you have to build a plot, then immediately go to Nook Miles islands to try to find a villager you like. If you don't pick someone yourself, Tom Nook will randomly pick someone for you.

Comment: Well, weve already got all 10 plots. Problem is when a villager leaves, she didn't have the time to find the villager she wanted to replace it. So the 'don't build it until you got it' doesn't work in this case.

Comment: The Polygon answer doesn't apply to at least the beggining of the game. I "pre recruited" a villager on an island and she didn't appear until a plot was built for her. I'll try to farm the islands now that I have 9 plots and am in the "endgame" to check if some villagers appear.

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is requesting to relocate the building before anyone moves in. Take your time finding the right villager in the meantime